# How to convert string to json in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

Here the code to list the data's in a csv file which is stored in S3 using nodejs code  but I want the output as expected output which is posted in below. Can someone help me to achieve that

CODE:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const express = require('express')
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');

const app = express()

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId:'-----',
    secretAccessKey:'-------',
    region:'ap-south-1'
});

app.get('/s3',(req,res)=>{
const params = {
 Bucket:'xxxxx',
 Key:'sample_2.csv'
          };

          s3.getObject(params,async(err, result) => {
            if (err){
                return console.error(err);
            }
            res.send(result.Body.toString('utf-8'))
          });
        })


app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('listenning')
})
```

OUTPUT:

```
Id,Name,Age,Gender 1,sethu,24,male 2,vimal,23,male 3,thiyanesh,22,male
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[
{
"Id": "1",
"Name": "sethu",
"Age": "24",
"Gender": "male"
},
{
"Id": "2",
"Name": "vimal",
"Age": "23",
"Gender": "male"
},
{
"Id": "3",
"Name": "thiyanesh",
"Age": "22",
"Gender": "male"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON.parse() function

Comment: it showing the following error --> Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

Achieved the answer for my question

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const express = require('express')
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');

const app = express()

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId:'AKIAJGK3S66SQG5TZGPA',
    secretAccessKey:'j7f+8Z9hs3ebCkQXZi2MTnL8x5H0UIWLyEKnInI3',
    region:'ap-south-1'
});

app.get('/s3',(req,res)=>{
const params = {
 Bucket:'wavicle-1',
 Key:'sample_2.csv'
          };

          s3.getObject(params,async(err, result) => {
            if (err){
                return console.error(err);
            }
            // res.send(result.Body.toString('utf-8'))
          
// const result = fs.readFileSync('./sample.csv','utf8')
neatCsv(result.Body)
    .then((parsedData) => res.send(parsedData));
        })
    })


app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('listenning')
})
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
{
"Id": "1",
"Name": "sethu",
"Age": "24",
"Gender": "male"
},
{
"Id": "2",
"Name": "vimal",
"Age": "23",
"Gender": "male"
},
{
"Id": "3",
"Name": "thiyanesh",
"Age": "22",
"Gender": "male"
}
]
```